# How can I upload multiple files with drupal 7?

Tags: file-upload, drupal-7, drupal-forms

I'm making a drupal 7 module that contains a form and I would like to upload multiple files in a row. Currently I'm using a managed_file type of input field.

```
$form['attachment'] = array(
                            '#title' => t('Attachment'),
                            '#type' => 'managed_file',
                            '#default_value' => variable_get('attachment', ''),
                          '#upload_location' => 'public://perm/',
                            );
```

This gives me the upload button, but only lets me upload one file. Is there a way I can tell this form to upload a file and still keep the option for a second upload open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out the new ajax system, it's pretty easy to implement, it should allow you to trigger an ajax callback once the file has been selected to add additional file fields to the form dynamically, just google "drupal 7 ajax" and you'll find dozens of examples

Answer (score 0):

have you checked to see if this is what you need? http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget