# Multiple file upload field in custom module using drupal 7 Form API

Tags: drupal-7

I'm searching for a way to add a field in a custom form that will allow me to upload a list of files like this one : [image: Like this one] which is a screenshot of a File field of the file module.

I tried this : http://ygerasimov.com/d7-zip-archive-custom-file-multiple-upload
which uses ajax and custom code. My files are saved in DB but not displayed when I reload the page... I tried to make it work but with no luck.

I really hope that someone will be able to help me.
Thanks in advance,
Hervé

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808207/how-can-i-upload-multiple-files-with-drupal-7

Answer (score 2):

You can used this for custom multiple upload fields:

```
$form['file'] = array(
  '#type' => 'file',
  '#name' => 'files[]',
  '#title' => t('Upload some photos'),
  '#description' => t('JPG\'s, GIF\'s, and PNG\'s only, 10MB Max Size'),
  '#attributes' => array('multiple' => 'multiple'),
);
```